# How to request run-time recording permission on Android 6.0?

Tags: android, appcelerator, audio-recording, appcelerator-titanium, runtime-permissions

Since Android 6.0, we need to request permissions during app runtime.

In my app, i'm using local storage, camera, geolocation and audio recording permissions.

So, requesting for local storage, camera and geolocation is ok with that snippet : 
https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti510/blob/master/app/controllers/permissions.js

But i've not found how to request for audio recording permission...I actually use titutorial.audiorecorder module for Android and it crashes when i tried to record since Android 6.0 because permission for recording is not enable.

More informations on my environment :

```
Operating System

Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.3
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 17179869184

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
  npm Version                 = 2.11.3

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.6

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.2.0.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/****/#/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.0.GA
  Target Platform             = android

Appcelerator Studio 4.5.0.201602170821
```

tiapp.xml

```
<manifest>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
...
...

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [ti.permissions](http://gitt.io/component/ti.permissions) module and a recompiled version of TiSDK :

- Go under your Titanium SDK directory eg: `/Users/[YOUR USER]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/`
- Duplicate the 5.2.0.GA directory and rename it as 5.2.0.WhatYouWant
- Go under `android` subdir and replace `titanium.jar` with this jar : https://github.com/AppWerft/Tierstimmenarchiv/blob/master/modules/android/titanium.jar
- After that in your project, inside the `tiapp.xml` replace `<sdk-version>5.2.0.GA</sdk-version>` with your new named SDK (5.2.0.WhatYouWant) don't forget to insert `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>` inside the `tiapp.xml` under the `<android .... >` node

and after that, you can request storage permission with this snippet:

```
if (!require('ti.permissions').hasPermission('android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'))
require('ti.permissions').requestPermissions(['android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'], function(e) {
    if (e.success != 0)
        Ti.API.debug("Permissions OK");
    else
        Ti.API.warn("Permissions denied");
});
```

Comment: I can't see my 5.2.0.GA sdk folder in /Users/[me]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/... I only see older SDK folders 3.5.1.GA and 5.0.2.GA ?!! Is there another path for 5.2.0.GA location ?

Comment: Ok, i found my 5.2.0.GA sdk path and doing all of instructions above. I no longer have the error but the callback function is not executing after requesting permission...I use the last version of the ti.permissions module (v0.4)

Comment: I've created a JIRA ticket you can watch to get this fixed in the SDK: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20544