# Android 6.0 audio permissions and titanium.jar in 5.2.2GA

Tags: android, appcelerator, audio-recording, appcelerator-titanium, runtime-permissions

In this question [How to request run-time recording permission on Android 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890378/how-to-request-run-time-recording-permission-on-android-6-0), there is link to a new (temp) .jar to work around the issue that I would like to use.  Can I use this Jar file with 5.2.2GA?

Comment: What you ran into is [TIMOB-20544](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20544) but you'll be able to check and request any permission in Titanium 5.4 (June) with [TIMOB-20320](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20320). Until then you could either use a custom built SDK patched with the PR for TIMOB-20320 or the workaround mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890378/how-to-request-run-time-recording-permission-on-android-6-0

Comment: I think you may have answered my question - but to confirm - The workaround in your link (same as mine) can be used with 5.2.2GA as well as 5.2.0GA ?  Or do I have to use 5.2.0GA for this workaround? Oh and huge thanks for the links to those issues, now watching them.