# Play audio Stream with AudioTrack in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

When I try to execute this part of code in android Lollipop version. Everything is ok. But in Marshmallow version is not working :

```
public static void play() {

    InputStream generetedStream =  ...;

    int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    AudioTrack trackw = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] lin = new byte[bufferSize];
    trackw.play();

    int i = 0;
    if (generetedStream != null) {
        while (generetedStream != null && (i = generetedStream.read(lin, 0, bufferSize)) > -1) {
            trackw.write(lin, 0, lin.length);
        }
    }

}
```

Added permissions :

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
> ```

is there any changing AudioTrack in Marshmallow version ???

Comment: don't you forget to Request Storage / etc Permissions at runtime? You are playing from storage / internet / resources / generate?

Comment: For android version 5 everything is ok. but in version 6 there is breaking in voice

Comment: I got it. Asked not about it. `InputStream generetedStream` from resource or internet or storage or are you generating it by your self?

Comment: generetedStream is generated by myself. I have already check that there is not problem

Comment: Write permissions to Android Manifest is not enough on Android 6.+. You should request them at runtime before using it. Read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). In your case first of all it should be [RECORD_AUDIO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890378/how-to-request-run-time-recording-permission-on-android-6-0)

Comment: OK. I'm testing run-time  permission. I will say the result

Comment: @VladimirKulyk I have always such warning : 

w/audiotrack releasebuffer() track disabled due to previous underrun restarting

Comment: @FarizAgayev Are you on a mobile with api 23 or are you targeting api 23?

Answer (score 3):

Try to set runtime permission for version `6.0`.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    } else {
        // your code
    }
}else{
    // your code
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission granted -code

            } else {

                // permission not granted - code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can add other permission whichever required...

Comment: Problem is not how can I write runtime permission .  Problem is why AudioTrack is not working with Marshmallow. But same code is ok for Lollipop.