# how can i add this permission to my Titanium Appcelerator project :"READ_PHONE_STATE" for android 6

Tags: permissions, appcelerator, android-6.0-marshmallow

i want to get my terminal IMEI , and for that i need a READ_PHONE_STATE permission
i added my to my tiapp.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

but i still get this error
[image]

Comment: where in the `tiapp` did you add it?

Comment: @RenePot i added it in the <android> node

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35690244/4678661) help you ? in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant some permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app

Comment: i understood the principle , but i need it for my appcelerator project not android Java , so i tried this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890378/how-to-request-run-time-recording-permission-on-android-6-0 
but the call back function is not executed